# When I hit the endpoint I'm getting whitelabel error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am making a simple api which is return a string when i try to access the api i'm getting white label error.

**Demo2Application.java**

```
package com.demo.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**MyContoller.java**

```
    package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/helloworld")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
    
}
```

**This error i'm getting**

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri May 12 17:51:33 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

**application.properties**

server.port=8888

**log messages**

```
2023-05-12T18:22:18.611+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.demo.app.Demo2Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:18.617+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.demo.app.Demo2Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.100+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.105+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.105+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.148+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.148+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 500 ms
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.306+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:19.312+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.demo.app.Demo2Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Demo2Application in 0.878 seconds (process running for 1.281)
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:36.791+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:36.792+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-05-12T18:22:36.792+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m58001[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8888-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

**endpoint**

```
http://localhost:8888/helloworld
```

Comment: Please share the application.properties and what url are you calling and the logs of the application.

Comment: there is nothing in application.properties

Comment: please include imports of your classes as well.

Comment: can somebody please help me in this

Comment: How are you *calling* the endpoint?

Comment: include packages as well please Alex of your classes, copy the entire content of your class and share it as text

Comment: could anyone help me in this out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your spring-boot application doesn't "see" the controller. (It is in sibling package)

Please read:
[structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code).

Answer (score 1):

Move your main class from

```
package com.demo.app;
```

to

```
package com.demo;
```

Your are getting 404 because starting point of scanning all Spring beans ( in your example @RestController ), is all subpackages starting from a package where your main class is located.

So if your main class is located in `package com.demo.app;`
your Spring Boot application will be scanning for all packages that are within `package com.demo.app;`. And since your controller is located in `package com.demo.controller;` it will not get picked up.

But if you move your main class to package `com.demo;` that will tell Spring to scan all subpackages of package `com.demo` that is `app` `demo` and any other package that you create.

Or you can keep your main class in

`com.demo.app;`

but move your controller to

`com.demo.app.controller;`

As long as your controller is in a subpackage of your main class location, your controller will be picked up.